# end of jquery fadeIn() has a 'bump' in Chrome

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm using a very simple fadeIn and fadeOut in Chrome.  I just want one text element to fade out and another to fade in.  Working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/forgetcolor/7eR5Q/

The problem I'm having is that at the end of the fadeIn() there is an abrupt transition to the end state.  I call it a 'bump'.  The element fadesIn smoothly, but right at the end it loses that smoothness and finishes the fade all at once.

Is there a way to avoid this?

```
var cur = 1;
$('#btn').click(function() {

    if (cur == 1) {
        $('#txt1').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('#txt2').fadeIn(500);
        });
        cur = 2;
    } else if (cur == 2) {
        $('#txt2').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('#txt1').fadeIn(500);
        });
        cur = 1;
    }
});​

body {
    background-color:#666;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    margin:20px;
}
#txt2 {display:none;}​

<div id="txt1">txt1</div>
<div id="txt2">txt2</div>
<br/><div id="btn">btn</div>​
```

UPDATE:

Here's a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2IGED0pkVg

My Chrome version number is 20.0.1132.21 beta (latest right now) on OSX

Chrome bug report submitted: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130801

Comment: It works perfectly in my Chrome.

Comment: interesting. i'm on OSX.  you?

Comment: Yeah I just tried it, and I'm having the same "bump" you're describing on Chrome OS X. Just so you know it's not just you...

Comment: Seems like bug in Chrome OS X.

Comment: Start comparing chrome version numbers to see if you can narrow it down further.

Comment: @VisioN I agree. And honestly it's not that bad, I'd just live with it. My Chrome is version 19.0.1084.52

Comment: @mix What's your version of Chrome?

Comment: added my version # and a video to the post

Comment: appears to work in Firefox and IE, not in Safari. so does that make it a clear Chrome issue or could it be a jquery issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I go ahead and turn off the webkit font smoothing, the dissolve works great:
http://jsfiddle.net/7eR5Q/19/
So apparantly it removes the smoothing during the transition and adds it after causing the "bump"

Comment: so does that make it a chrome bug or an osx bug?  and is there any workaround (other than removing font smoothing)?

Comment: webkit font smoothing is specific to osx browsers based on webkit.  If we change the property to antialiased : http://jsfiddle.net/7eR5Q/20/ it looks ok, and the animation is still smooth

Comment: nice, i'll add your fiddle to the bug report

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like the fadeIn is happening too quickly, increase the time up to 600,

```
$('#txt1').fadeIn(600); and $('#txt2').fadeIn(600);
```

seemed a bit more even for me.

Comment: 600 still has the bump I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the font smooth rendering  *bugging* on macbooks. Here is an [question from stackoverflow](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36752/problems-with-font-rendering-on-a-macbook-pro-using-external-24-lcd?answertab=votes#tab-top) of it.

**Edit:** you can improve you font rendering with *font smoothing* in *antialiased* ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-font/#font-smooth-prop)) mode. And here is [an article](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing) why you shouldn't use it in general.

`-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

Comment: then why only on some browsers and not others?

Comment: That is the age old question.

Answer (score 0):

For future users who come across this, I found this solution worked for me.

```
-webkit-opacity: .99;
```