# jQuery fadeOut() has no animation in specific situations. workaround?

Tags: jquery

I've run into a situation where a jQuery fadeOut() isn't working as expected. My test case is the Facebook profile homepage, on items of class `text`.  I'm doing this through userscripts, but my test case it just running in the console (I've loaded jQuery into the page using a [userscript](http://erikvold.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/6/14/using-jquery-with-a-user-script), but you can use your favorite method (paste it in, [jqueryify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbmifchmngifmadobkcpijhhldeeelkc) for chrome, etc.)).

Here's a demo movie: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fsh5nQY8n4k .  Movie shows the problem on Chrome, but I get similar behavior on Firefox and Safari (all OSX).

The lines of code I'm using here are: `$('.text').fadeOut();` and `$('.text').fadeIn();`

I've tried some workarounds, such as animating opacity directly, animating some of the fade first, and then animating the rest with a callback, setting the z-index for the item first, etc. I also tried turning on [webkit antialiasing, a workaround for another jquery animation bug in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856728/end-of-jquery-fadein-has-a-bump-in-chrome). None make a difference.

I'm guessing there's something going on with how Facebook has these elements coded, since I can't reproduce the problem with a jsfiddle (?)

Any ideas for getting that text to fade out as expected?

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7978#comment:6 This might help for the webkit issues. `display: list-item` seems to cause some issues

Comment: i don't see how this applies.  it's not a chrome-specific bug, it's not set to `display:list-item` (it's set to `inline-block`).

Answer (score 0):

Check the element you want to fadeIn/Out, is there a transistion? If yes, fadeIn/Out will not work.

This solved my problem, may help.